# actionscript calling javascript with Security Exception

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook

I have a swf hosted at domain A, and I have a html at domain B

My swf is able to be loaded from accessing the html at domain B.
However, the swf gets a

> SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation:
>   ExternalInterface caller http://domainA.com/TrialApp.swf cannot access
>   http://DomainB.com/.

The as3 is just the below:

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascript:_invite();");
```

I've also loaded the crossdomain policy file from Domain B during initialization.

```
Security.loadPolicyFile( "http://DomainB/crossdomain.xml" );
```

How do I go about solving this?

in my html, I have

```
allowscriptaccess='always'
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I believe that you do not need to prepend the `javascript` protocol directive in the `call` function parameter.

Comment: I found my answer, Since I'm working on facebook applications development, I have to use the FBJS bridge tag

see http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:fbjs-bridge
This proves I need to read up more about the technology before I jump headon into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob is right, you are not supposed to include the javascript protocol when using ExternalInterface.call().

I am far from certain that it will solve the security exception, but you could try to do:

```
ExternalInterface.call("_invite");
```

... instead of:

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascript:_invite();");
```

The documented way to use [ExternalInterface.call()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()) is ExternalInterface.call(functionName:String, ... arguments). In practice, you can also send a string that is a piece of JavaScript (without "javascript:"), and it will be executed, so ExternalInterface.call("_invite();") could also work.